# Regular Expression for Optional characters

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need to validate a file path. One of the directories can have a version number in it.

Following are the two possible kinds of path that I may encounter.

**Path 1**

```
File path = "/a/b/c/d_9000/p1=<val1>/p2=<val2>/p3=<val3>/<val4>"
```

**Expected Output**

```
Group 1 = d
Group 2 = 9000
Group 3 = val1
Group 4 = val2
Group 5 = val3
Group 6 = val4
```

**Path 2**

```
File Path = "/a/b/c/d/p1=<val1>/p2=<val2>/p3=<val3>/<val4>"
```

**Expected Output**

```
Group 1 = d
Group 2 = <null or empty string>
Group 3 = val1
Group 4 = val2
Group 5 = val3
Group 6 = val4
```

When each of these file paths is parsed, I need the above values in each group

Following is what I have tried

```
\/a\/b\/c\/(\w+)_([0-9]+)\/p1=(.*)\/p2=(.*)\/p3=(.*)\/(.*)
```

But this does not give me the right values for Group1 & Group 2

I tried adding the '?' after the underscore, but that does not help either.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\w` matches letters, digits **or `_`**. It is quantified with `+`, a greedy quantifier, and thus making the subsequent adjoining pattern optional match an empty string before a non-matching text. `(\w+)_?([0-9]+)\/` will grab all letter, digits, `_` up to the `/` in `d_9000/`, and only the last `0` will land in Group 3 since `[0-9]+` should match at least 1 digit.

You may exclude a `_` from `\w` using `[^\W_]` and make the `_([0-9]+)` pattern optional by wrapping it with an optional non-capturing group:

```
\/a\/b\/c\/([^\W_]+)(?:_([0-9]+))?\/p1=(.*)\/p2=(.*)\/p3=(.*)\/(.*)
            ^^^^^^^ ^^^         ^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d1sEm9/1/).

Or, make `\w` lazy rather than subtracting `_` from `\w` (if there can be `_` other than the one before the digits you need to capture):

```
\/a\/b\/c\/(\w*?)(?:_([0-9]+))?\/p1=(.*)\/p2=(.*)\/p3=(.*)\/(.*)
            ^^^^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d1sEm9/2).

[image]